# The Promoter badge is not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, bounty-badges

Is the promoter badge not working a known not-yet-implemented issue, or is it a bug?

Comment: Promoter, Campaigner, and Activist aren't implemented yet, but they should be sometime today. I'll tag this as status-completed when those badges are good to go.

Comment: ok, also add an answer so I can accept it when you're done. Thanks @emm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed: Promoter, Campaigner, and Activist are being awarded now.